# Is it possible to add manual control before auto-aligning layers in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, timelapse, layers, image-alignment

I have some shots of a construction site taken 1 month apart and I want to animate the construction progress.

Problem is, because of moving fences and other hard lines, some of my images aren't lining up properly with an auto align.

Is there a way to mark certain points in the images so that photoshop knows they are all the same?

For example, the 4 points of a wall as it is constructed. Currently some shots have fencing in front of the wall that is being confused with the actual wall and throwing those shots way off from the rest of the set.

Answer (score 3):

I've never had a reason to do this but to my knowledge there's no automatic way within Photoshop. You would need to just manually refine them as required. However, if you have the entire Adobe Creative Suite subscription than After Effects can make pretty short work of something like this using the [Motion Tracker](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/tracking-stabilizing-motion-cs5.html).

If you're making an animated timelapse it would probably be better all around to switch over to After Effects really.

Comment: I do have the whole suite, this could be a good jumping off point for after effects!

Thanks.